# Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. Exception from Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have this controller to update information in database:

```
public ActionResult EditOwner(Owner owner, int? [] selectedNewCars)
{
        var newOwner = new Owner();

        newOwner.Name = owner.Name;
        newOwner.Surname = owner.Surname;
        newOwner.Birthday = owner.Birthday;
        newOwner.ExperienceInYears = owner.ExperienceInYears;
        newOwner.OwnerId = owner.OwnerId;

        newOwner.Cars.Clear();

        if (selectedNewCars != null)
        {                
            foreach (int carId in selectedNewCars)
            {
                var car = db.GetCar(carId);
                newOwner.Cars.Add(car);
            }                          
        }

        db.UpdateOwner(newOwner);

        return RedirectToAction("OwnersInfo");
}
```

and this to update entry from repository class:

```
public void UpdateOwner(Owner item)
{            
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Save();
}
```

Get car by id:

```
public Car GetCar(int id)
{           
    return db.Cars.Include(p => p.Owners).FirstOrDefault(x => x.CarId == id);
}
```

Car model:

```
    public class Car
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CarId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Car model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Car mk.")]
    public string Mk { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Car price")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public int ReleaseDate { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Car type")]
    public CarType Type { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public List<Owner> Owners { get; }

    public Car()
    {
        Owners = new List<Owner>();          
    }
}
```

Owner model:

```
public class Owner
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client birthday")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client experience(in years)")]
    public int? ExperienceInYears { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select car")]      
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Owner()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}
```

My problem is this exception of EF:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGlP8.png)

Can anyone help? I have spent several days trying to resolve it and nothing..

Comment: Hi Oleksiy, would you mind sharing the details of how Owner and Car table are related in the database? To me it looks like the when you retrieve a car from db you also include owners of the car. And after that you add that car to the new owner. To me it looks like Car.Owners has already owner ojbect with the same id and that might be the reason behind this exception.

Comment: the problem here is that you set Modified only on one entity...have you tried to set it also on Car entities as modified?

Comment: Thanks for answers! Im working on this what you said, but this works fine when i try to create entry, i think that must work with update, but no..

 if (selectedCars != null)
            {
                foreach (int carId in selectedCars)
                {
                    var car = db.GetCar(carId);
                    newOwner.Cars.Add(car);
                }                                       
            }

Answer (score 0):

i found a problem. "owner" object must be recived from database, then modified, like this:

```
    public ActionResult EditOwner(Owner owner, int? [] selectedNewCars)
    {
        var newOwner = db.GetOwner(owner.OwnerId);

        newOwner.Name = owner.Name;
        newOwner.Surname = owner.Surname;
        newOwner.Birthday = owner.Birthday;
        newOwner.ExperienceInYears = owner.ExperienceInYears;
        newOwner.OwnerId = owner.OwnerId;

        newOwner.Cars.Clear();

        if (selectedNewCars != null)
        {                
            foreach (int carId in selectedNewCars)
            {
                var car = db.GetCar(carId);                    
                newOwner.Cars.Add(car);
            }                          
        }

        db.UpdateOwner(newOwner);

        return RedirectToAction("OwnersInfo");
    }
```